Error while creating woocommerce child category
Im developing a plugin that will bulk upload products from NextGen Gallery. I am using NGG albums as parent categories and NGG galleries as subcategories. I have two functions that create album and gallery and also should create parent category nad child category, however only parent category is being created.
function create_new_album($album_name) {
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->insert(
        "{$wpdb->prefix}ngg_album",
        array(
            'name' => sanitize_text_field($album_name),
            'slug' => sanitize_title($album_name),
            'sortorder' => base64_encode(json_encode(array()))
        ),
        array('%s', '%s', '%s')
    );
    if ($result === false) {
        // Handle error, for example log the error and return false
        return false;
    }

    wp_insert_term($album_name, 'product_cat');

    return get_album_id_by_name($album_name);
}


function create_new_gallery($gallery_name, $album) {
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->insert(
        "{$wpdb->prefix}ngg_gallery",
        array(
            'name' => sanitize_text_field($gallery_name),
            'slug' => sanitize_title($gallery_name),
            'path' => "/wp-content/gallery/" . sanitize_title($gallery_name) . "/",
            'title' => $gallery_name
        ),
        array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')
    );

    if ($result === false) {
        return false;
    }

    // Insert the gallery category into WooCommerce
    $new_category_args = array(
        'parent' => find_category_id($album->slug),
    );

    $category = wp_insert_term($gallery_name, 'product_cat', $new_category_args);

    return get_gallery_id_by_name($gallery_name);
}

function find_category_id($category_name) { 
    $category = get_term_by('name', $category_name, 'product_cat'); 

    if ($category) { 
        return $category->term_id; 
    }
}


function get_album_id_by_name($album_name) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Retrieve the ID based on the album name
    $album_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ngg_album WHERE slug = %s",
        sanitize_title($album_name)
    ));

    return $album_id;
}
function get_gallery_id_by_name($gallery_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    // Retrieve the ID based on the album name
    $gallery_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT gid FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ngg_gallery WHERE slug = %s",
        sanitize_title($gallery_name)
    ));

    return $gallery_id;
}



I tried to add the names to the error log: All of them match, I don't see why it doesn't create the child category
I'm running WordPress locally.
I have tried creating the new album and new gallery through my plugin, both gallery and album are created in the ngg database, but WooCommerce category is only created for album, not for gallery.
I forgot to mention that the code was running just fine until I added more functionalities to the plugin, and now it had stopped working. I have tried retrieving the old code that was working, but even then it didn't work.


The problem comes from find_category_id() function…

Here is the function:
function find_category_id($category_name){
$category = get_term_by('name', $category_name, 'product_cat');
if ($category) {
return $category->term_id;
}
}

Update your question code with all missing functions like get_album_id_by_name() and get_gallery_id_by_name()

Apperantly seperating the plugin into submenus worked, not sure why it wouldnt work but having a submenu for creating albums and galleries solved the issue
EDIT: OH MY GOD, im sorry for this whole question. It was just my mistake, i have a function that should delete albums/galleries etc. and im using one of the functions to also delete all the products before adding them so they are not there twice. Well when i was writing the function i also added a line to delete the whole category beacuse at that time it was what i needed and then i also used it when creating products. so the category was okay i just deleted it right before using it. The reason it started working before was that i commented out the delete products function just in case and i didnt realize that was what was causing this bug
